# Intellij lost project settings after adding dependency in pom.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm using Intellij IDEA 15 on Mac OS to do SpringMVC development. There is a problem that once I modify the pom.xml (add or remove a dependency configuration), the change I made in the project structure such as set the root path of the web project or make /src/main/java a source folder instead of a package folder will be lost, how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It's by design, in a Maven based project all the changes must be performed in `pom.xml`, IntelliJ IDEA will import them. `src/main/java` is already Maven default source root unless you override it with `<sourceDirectory>`, so the real problem is not clear.

Comment: I don't know why, but the sourceDirectory in the pom.xml is src, changing it to src/main/java solve the problem. Thank you, CrazyCoder.

Answer (score 2):

CrazyCoder's comment solved my problem. After checking the pom.xml, I found that the sourceDirectory is src and the warSourceDirectory is webapp, changing the sourceDirectory to src/main/java and warSourceDirectory to src/main/webapp solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design -- it's how maven and intellij work. If you configure something specific about the project structure, dependencies, or build instructions in idea then it'll be lost when you reimport your pom.

Your final comment suggests that you don't have your code in the conventional layout for a java project, so you can either configure maven/intellij to use your current layout or you can just do what almost everyone else does and chnage your code to the standard structure. You can find more information about maven's standard directory structure from the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), or many stack overflow questions.